# How to put RecyclerView below CollapsingToolbarLayout and responsive to toolbar when collapsed in Android?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-coordinatorlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I am developing an Android App. In my app I am using, CollapsingtoolbarLayout together with RecyclerView. Both are working. But I am having a problem with positioning them. What I want is I want RecyclerView directly below Collapsing Toobar and I want RecyclerView go up together with toolbar when it is collapsed. But my code is not working as I expected.

This is what happening now.

[image]

As you can see recycler view is having fixed position covered with toolbar. It is not responsive to collapsed toolbar.

This is my XML layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/dc_rv_destination"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/htab_appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/htab_collapse_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/main_activity_parallax_initial_height"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/htab_header"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@drawable/apple"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:text="HELLO"
                    android:textSize="20dp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </RelativeLayout>
            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/main_activity_toolbar_height"
                android:gravity="top"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:titleMarginTop="13dp" />
          <!--  <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/htab_tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white" />-->
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

In activity, I did not configured anything excepting initializing RecyclerView and setting data to it.

This is how I set RecyclerView in activity

```
 private void setDestinationRecyclerView()
    {
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getBaseContext());
        rcDestinations.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        rcDestinations.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        regionsList = new ArrayList<Region>();
        destinationsAdapter = new DestinationsAdapter(regionsList,getBaseContext());
        rcDestinations.setAdapter(destinationsAdapter);
        //add items and notify data changed
    }
```

So, how can I make RecyclerView responsive to CollapsingToolbarLayout when it is collapsed?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I don't know if you have already fixed it. However you are missing

```
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
```

in your RecyclerView.

Try like this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/dc_rv_destination"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
```

Comment: Don't use ```android:layout_height="wrap_content"```! Always use ```match_parent```.