# How to put a list (RecyclerView or Listview) inside a CollapsingToolbar?

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview, toolbar, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I'm trying to put a scrollable list inside a CollapsingToolbar, but it's not working. The list appears but does not scroll. I want to put a list that appears inside the Toolbar. For example, it is possible to place an image inside a CollapsingToolbar, rather than an image I want to place a type of scrool view. So the layout of the screen will have two lists: one main below the Toolbar and another within the Toobar, which appears when Tooblar is expanded.

```
  <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|start"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="250dp">

                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/ultimate_recyclerview"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:scrollbars="vertical" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

The CollapsingToolbar is working properly and I get the click on each item but the list does not scroll.

Does anyone know how I can do this?

Comment: already answered here [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39040981/5805371)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to put RecyclerView below CollapsingToolbarLayout and responsive to toolbar when collapsed in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37507868/how-to-put-recyclerview-below-collapsingtoolbarlayout-and-responsive-to-toolbar)

Comment: That's not my question. What I want is to put a list inside a Toolbar not below it. In a CollapsingToolbar it is possible to add an image, instead of that image I want to add a list that I can scroll.