# Android : Recyclerview scrolling with Collapsing toolbar issue

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

In my app I am using, CollapsingtoolbarLayout together with RecyclerView. Both are working. But I am having a problem with scrolling them. What I want is I want whenever i scroll RecyclerView directly below Collapsing Toobar and I want RecyclerView go up together with toolbar when it is collapsed. but this is not happening whenever i scroll recyclerview first it goes behind corousal then at some point corousal scrolls .But my code is not working as I expected.

following is my code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">


<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$Behavior">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/black_theme"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        app:title="@string/app_name">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/corousal_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <include
                android:id="@+id/layout_sticky_home"
                layout="@layout/item_sticky_header_rt" />

            <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
                android:id="@+id/rvcarousal"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:visibility="visible"
                app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
                app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="h,3:4"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/layout_sticky_home" />

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="-8dp"
                android:background="@drawable/bg_gradient"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/linlay_pager"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/rv_carousal"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/rv_carousal" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linlay_pager"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/rv_carousal"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/rv_carousal"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/rv_carousal"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/rv_carousal" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


    </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_20sdp"
        android:clipChildren="false"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

i tried many solution but mostly i found in SO's answer to give @string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior to recyclerview but it wont work

Comment: Try adding a toolbar inside collapsing toolbar layout (sibling of constraint layout) and add `app:layout_collapseMode="pin"` to the toolbar layout. This will help collapsing layout to pin to the toolbar while scrolling up.

Comment: @JeelVankhede im facing exaclty same issue like which this user facing refer ss in this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37507868/how-to-put-recyclerview-below-collapsingtoolbarlayout-and-responsive-to-toolbar ...
also there is not requirement for toolbar so thats why i didnt used toolbar

Comment: @JeelVankhede I want RecyclerView go up together with toolbar but right now first it will go first behind toolbar n then at some point full recycler view gets visible when toolbar collapsed

Comment: @JeelVankhede got some suggestions?

Comment: Why do you wrap the RecyclerView`in a `RelativeLayout`? .. get rid of it and transfer the `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` to the `RecyclerView`

Comment: @Zain doesnt work that as well

Comment: @androiddev I recently implemented the same thing and in my use case recycler view started scrolling before collapsing toolbar reacts. Hence I had to introduce a pinned view inorder to tell collapsing toolbar to collapse. first before recycler view scroll happens. Also that wrapping recycler view inside relative layout won’t fix the issue and I would recommend using recyclerview at root instead.

Comment: @JeelVankhede using recyclerview at root also didn't worked though

Comment: @JeelVankhede and zain can you all help me over here -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77879511/not-able-to-add-swipetorefreshlayout-inside-the-collapsetoollbar-android

Answer (score 0):

I understand the problem, i can suggest you some solution that you can give them a try.

**1. Nested Scrolling:**

- You can disable nested scrolling in the RecyclerView and set `android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"` on the RecyclerView. This might prevents the RecyclerView from interfering with the CollapsingToolbarLayout's scrolling behavior and also lead to touch events not being handled correctly.

**2. AppBarLayout Configuration:**

- Set the app:layout_scrollFlags attribute: Use `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"` on the CollapsingToolbarLayout. This ensures the RecyclerView scrolls together with the CollapsingToolbarLayout when it collapses.

hope it helps.

Comment: Tried this as well but didn't worked

Answer (score 0):

Try using **`NestedScrollView`** as a parent for **`RecyclerView`** instead of **`RelativeLayout`**

Comment: Still doesn't worked...but using nested scrollview indeed it is bad practice with recycler as it will stop recycling of recyclerview

Comment: can you share the video of the exact problem? so that we can understand the scenario better.

Comment: Refer this links ss https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37507868/how-to-put-recyclerview-below-collapsingtoolbarlayout-and-responsive-to-toolbar I'm facing exactly issue but string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior didn't worked for me